# Preimage of SHA512 with a known suffix

Tags: hash

Is it possible to figure out what `$arg1` is if I know both `$arg2` and `$arg3` in addition to `$hash`?

`$hash = hash('sha512', $arg1 . $arg2 . $arg3);`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `.` represents concatenation, no, except in the specific case that `$arg1` is the empty string.  You're trying to perform a [preimage attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack), which is one of the things that SHA512 is designed to be resistant to.

Further, knowing `$arg2` and `$arg3` does not let you speed up a brute-force attack on `$arg1`, because for each candidate value for `$arg1`, `$arg2` and `$arg3` will modify the checksum differently.  (If you knew `$arg1` and `$arg2` and were looking for `$arg3`, you could precompute the partial checksum of the first two values as the starting point for each try at finding `$arg3`)

Comment: The exception should not be: "`$arg1` _is the empty string_" but rather: `$arg1` is low entropy, including of small size, e.g. a password; in that case, it is possible to figure out `$arg1` by exhaustive search.

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can depending on the entropy contained in `$arg1`.

For example, say you know `$arg2=Will you marry me?`

and 
`$arg3=\r\n\r\nBob`.

If Bob has been dating two girls, say Alice and Trudy, you could guess that either `$arg1=Alice,\r\n`

or `$arg1=Trudy,\r\n`.

A simple test of both possibilities will tell you the answer since you know `$hash`.

If `$arg2` and `$arg3` are known then `$hash = hash('sha512', $arg1)` has the same search space as `$hash = hash('sha512', $arg1 . $arg2 . $arg3)`.

So if `$arg1` has a small search space, you could do an exhaustive search.

Comment: +1 but I'm missing the part in the answer that states that this should not result in less search space than just `hash('sha512', $arg1)` (and the answer of Mark is missing this particular argument)

Comment: @owlstead It is the same search space as <code>hash('sha512', $arg1)</code>.

Comment: You don't have to explain that to *me* :) edited into answer, if you don't mind. Hmm, maybe I should have switched the equations in the edit...

Comment: @owlstead, I see. I was missing your point. It is clear now.